# java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: Exception from call site #0 bootstrap method

Tags: android, kotlin, signalr

I get the error: 'java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: Exception from call site #0 bootstrap method' whenever I call this line in Android with SignalR

> hubConnection =
> HubConnectionBuilder.create("http://192.168.137.1:5000/movehub").build();

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder.create("http://192.168.137.1:5000/movehub").build();

        btnConnect.setOnClickListener {
            if (btnConnect.text.toString() == "Connect") {
                if (hubConnection.connectionState == HubConnectionState.DISCONNECTED) {
                    hubConnection.start()
                    btnConnect.text = "Disconnect"
                }
            } else if (btnConnect.text.toString() == "Disconnect") {
                if (hubConnection.connectionState == HubConnectionState.CONNECTED) {
                    hubConnection.stop()
                    btnConnect.text = "Connect"
                }
            }
        }
```

This is in my gradle:

> implementation 'com.microsoft.signalr:signalr:3.0.0'

I get the same error even if I use

```
implementation 'com.microsoft.signalr:signalr:1.0.0'
```

Please see the whole error:

```
Process: com.tryouts.androidclient, PID: 22480
    java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: Exception from call site #0 bootstrap method
        at com.microsoft.signalr.HubConnection.<init>(HubConnection.java:159)
        at com.microsoft.signalr.HttpHubConnectionBuilder.build(HttpHubConnectionBuilder.java:122)
        at com.tryouts.androidclient.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:18)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Bootstrap method returned null
        at com.microsoft.signalr.HubConnection.<init>(HubConnection.java:159) 
        at com.microsoft.signalr.HttpHubConnectionBuilder.build(HttpHubConnectionBuilder.java:122) 
        at com.tryouts.androidclient.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:18) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: SUGGESTION: Try setting JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 in your build.gradle: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60991383/421195

Comment: Yes it did Sir. Thank you. I already upvoted the answer and the question.